# What does referring to a child relation of an object return?

Tags: soql, custom-object, list, relationships, master-detail

Custom Object Maintenance_Request__c has master Detail relationship to Custom Object Vehicle__c (Child Relationship Name = Maintenance_Requests).
In the Following code

```
       for(Vehicle__c veh : v){
            Vehicle__c vi = [select Id ,(select Status__c from Maintenance_Requests__r) from Vehicle__c where Id = :veh.Id];
            integer duplicateflag=0;
            for ( Maintenance_Request__c m : vi.Maintenance_Requests__r){
                if(m.Status__c!='Completed'||m.Status__C!='Cancelled')
                {
                  duplicateflag=1;
                  }
            }
     }
```

What Does

```
vi.Maintenance_Requests__r
```

Return?
A list of Maintenance_Requests__c or a single Maintenance_Request__c.

Also keep in mind

```
List<Maintenance_Request__c> a = vi.Maintenance_Requests__r;
Maintenance_Request__c b = vi.Maintenance_Requests__r;
```

Both of these statements cause no error.(At least Showing no error in problems tab of Developer Console)

Answer (score 1):

Formally, a child relationship refers to a `List<sObject>` for the specified type (e.g. `List<Maintenance_Request__c>`), or a QueryLocator if certain conditions are met (more than 2k rows or too many fields returned).

However, note that because of a special rule in Apex, you can assign a query result to a non-list object. If there is not exactly one element in the list, you will get an error (*List has no rows for assignment to SObject* or *List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject*).

```
Account record = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1];
```

Comment: But that would be a runtime error right.Will it show any errors in problems tab of developer console?

Comment: @DonalShijan Correct. You should not get a compiler error if the list is from "sObject land" or meets certain other conditions (e.g. from an inline query). You can see this effect with this quick code sample: `Account a = new Account();
Contact c = a.Contacts;` (throws the no rows for assignment error).

Comment: @DonalShijan Yes, it's supposed to be a "feature," but is very confusing to newcomers. For example, this code runs without error: `Account a = new Account();
Object c = a.Contacts;
System.assert(c instanceOf List<Contact>);
System.assert(c instanceOf Contact);`